# Router Saturation or Buffer Bloat?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I have what you would call an advanced home networking setup- I've got a SB6183 on Comcast at an advertised speed of 250 mbps going to an Edimax BR-6478AC connected to about 6 wired devices (through 2 separate gigabit unmanaged switches) and a variety of wireless devices (~5-6 normally). Recently, since I upgraded my Comcast from 100 mbps to 250 mbps, I've noticed that when I download large files on one device (such as Steam games), all other devices on the network (wired and wireless) are effectively "shut out" of the internet- pings work, but anything more fails.

I had thought that this was a case of buffer bloat- but the DSLReports speed test reports minimal buffer bloat (6 ms, A score). Is this still a case of buffer bloat? Is this a case of some other flavor of router issues? Do I need to replace my router with something more robust or would I be better off working the settings of my current router?

Answer (score 0):

Here's another test to confirm/deny bufferbloat (see https://www.bufferbloat.net/projects/bloat/wiki/Tests_for_Bufferbloat/)

1. Start a ping somewhere (say, google.com) (`ping -t google.com`)
2. Start your Steam download
3. Watch how the times in the ping results change.
4. If the ping times get much larger, it's bufferbloat.
5. If they stay relatively the same, it's not bufferbloat. The "shut out" of other services you're seeing may be caused by the router not being able to keep up with 250 mbps service.

I'll be interested to hear what others on the list say about this router.